# UNIX program to search a list and produce requested report, is not returning the specified information

Tags: bash, unix

```
#!/bin/bash

# search medicine list and generate a report
# script name: search.sh

# Loop to ask medication code and generic name or dose
# Enter 'ZZZ' to quit
while :
do
# taking medication code from the user
echo -n "Enter Medication code? "
read -r mcode  
# converting medication code to upper case for comparision if necessary
mcode=$(echo $mcode|tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')
# if mcode is ZZZ, quit from the outer while loop
if [ "$mcode" == 'ZZZ' ]
then
    break
fi
# loop to ensure generic name or dose is passed correctly
# if generic name is 'G' or 'D' this loop terminates
while :
 do
# taking generic name or dose as input from user
echo -n "See Generic Name (G/g) or Dose (D/d) ? "
read gname
# converting gname to upper for comparision in if condition below
gname=$(echo $gname|tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')
if [ "$gname" == 'G' -o "$gname" == 'D' ]
then
    break
 else
   echo "Please enter only G or D."
 fi
done

# grepping given mcode in the medslist file and redirecting to file 
/tmp/result
grep $mcode medslist>/tmp/result
# traversing through /tmp/result file and print required category and 
medcode
while read line
do

genname=$(echo $line|cut -c5-25)
dose=$(echo $line|cut -c26-39)

if gname='G'
then echo "$genname"
elif gname='D'
then echo "$dose"
fi
done</tmp/result
# below condition will be true if medication code is wrong
if [ ! -s /tmp/result ]
then
 echo "No such medication code"
fi
done
```

The problem i am having at this time is when  i request the dosage information it is returning identical output to the output produced when the generic name is requested. Everything else seems to be working fine except i just can't get the program to display the dosage information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues about quoting: paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and follow the recommendations.

However the main problem is this

```
if gname='G'
then echo "$genname"
elif gname='D'
then echo "$dose"
fi
```

You are checking the exit status of a variable assignment, not the result of a test command. You need

```
if [ "$gname" = 'G' ]
then echo "$genname"
elif [ "$gname" = 'D' ]
then echo "$dose"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it. The site is incredible thank you very much again for the resource.